# Extracting values from a nested dictionary structure in python

Tags: python, dictionary

My code and data structure that results in the output below looks like this :

```
    Actions = set()

     # loop through and obtain a list of files and commands
    for item in d['server']:
         Actions.add('{action}'.format(**item))


     print(Actions)
     commands = list(Actions)

     commands = list(Actions)
```

Output:

```
     Actions = {"{'command1': ['uptime'], 'path': ['/var/log/syslog']}", "{'command1': ['df -h'], 'path': ['/var/log/auth.log']}"}
```

I need to extract the commands and paths separately and something like this doesn't work.

```
    print(commands[0]['command1'])

    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "read_shell_yaml.py", line 46, in 
    print(commands[0]['command1'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: It looks like your `Actions` is just a set with one `str` in it

Comment: yes that's why I converted it into a list to extract - see commands[]

Comment: Why don't you keep it as a `dict`?  It's obvious that's what `d['server']` is.  I'm unsure why you turned it into a string first.

Comment: so I can format it better but I suppose I could do so using dict - `d['server']` itself .

Comment: `d['server'][actions]['command1']` . - something like this does not work however. So how can I extract the elements

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your `item` dict into a string with the `str.format` method, which prevents the latter code from extracting items from the dict.

For your purpose, a more fitting data structure for `Actions` would be a dict indexed by the command instead:

```
Actions = {}
for item in d['server']:
    Actions[items.pop('command1')] = item
```

so that you can later iterate through the items of the `Actions` dict like this:

```
for command, properties in Actions.items():
    print(command, properties['path'])
```

Comment: `dict` is not immutable so it cannot be hashed and cannot be added to a `set` @nlp

Comment: My bad. There is no reason you should use a set here. I've updated my answer with a more fitting data structure for the purpose then.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in the way that you did, you can at the end:

```
import json
content = json.loads(command[0].replace("'", '"'))
content['command1'] #prints ['df -h']
```